# Vaadin window on top of modal window

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

In my application I'd like to have a help window. It should be a window with information to the current context and can be activated by pressing F1.
This works so far, but the problem comes when the application has an open modal window.
If the user presses F1 while having a modal window open the help window opens normally and is visible. If the user now goes back to the modal window, by clicking on it, the help window goes to the back and is behind the modality curtain.

I managed to keep the help window on top by setting the z-index in the sylesheet:

```
.helpwin {
     z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```

The problem is now that the help window seems to be on top but is still kind of disabled. It is not movable or closable. It is not even possible anymore to select some text on it.

Funnily this does not happen if the debug mode is enabled (?debug in url).

How can I prevent this and why does it happen?

Thanks,
Raffael

Answer (score 0):

Well it sounds kind of normal since you have a modal window it is not supposed to let focus to other windows. You could perhaps add a `BlurListener` to the help window, and close it as soon as it looses focus.